# Finding the highest R^2 value

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new in python and my problem is that I have a given set of data:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1,5)
y=np.arange(5,9)
```

My problem is to find a number n (not necessarily an integer) that will give me the highest value of R^2 value when I plot y^n vs x. I'm thinking of generating n for example as:

```
n=np.linspace(1,9,100)
```

I don't know how to execute my idea. My other means is to resort to brute force of generating n and raising y for each value of n. After getting that value (let's say y1), I will plot y1 vs x (which means I have to generate 100 plots. But I have no clue on how to get the R^2 value ( for a linear fit) for a given plot.

What I want to do is to have a list (or array) of R^2 values:

```
R2= np.array() #a set containing the R^2 values calculated from the plots
```

and find the max value on that array and from there, find the plot that gave that R^2 value thus I will find a particular n. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify, What does R^2 represents?

Comment: @FortMauris R^2 gives the correlation between two quantities. If I plot y vs x and got an R^2 value of 1 (max value), it means that they're correlated with each other. The closer R^2 to a value of 1, the better

Comment: R² is also called [the coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the pandas library, this problem is very easy to express:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

x = pandas.Series(np.arange(1,5))
y = pandas.Series(np.arange(5,9))
exponents = exponents = np.linspace(1, 9, 100)

r2s = {n:pandas.ols(x=x, y=y**n).r2 for n in exponents}
max(r2s.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
#>>> (1.0, 1.0)
```

Breaking this down:

1. the `pandas.Series` object is an indexed column of data. It's like a `numpy` array, but with extra features. In this case, we only care about it because it is something we can pass to `pandas.ols`.
2. `pandas.ols` is a basic implementation of least-squares regression. You can do this directly in numpy with `numpy.linalg.lstsq`, but it won't directly report the R-squared values for you. To do it with pure numpy, you'll need to get the sum of squared residuals from numpy's `lstsq` and then perform the formulaic calculations for R-squared manually. You could write this as a function for yourself (probably a good exercise).
3. The stuff inside the `{..}` is a `dict` comprehension. It will iterate over the desired exponents, perform the `ols` function for each, and report the `.r2` attribute (where the R-squared statistic is stored) indexed by whatever exponent number was used to get it.
4. The final step is to call `max` on a sequence of the key-value pairs in `r2s`, and `key` tells max that it is the second element (the R-squared) by which elements are compared.

An example function to do it with just `np.linalg.lstsq` is here ([good explanation for calculating R2 in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054191/converting-numpy-lstsq-residual-value-to-r2)):

```
def r2(x, y):
    x_with_intercept = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    coeffs, resid = np.linalg.lstsq(x_with_intercept, y)[:2]
    return 1 - resid / (y.size * y.var())[0]
```

Then in pure numpy the above approach:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,5)
y = np.arange(5,9)
exponents = np.linspace(1, 9, 100)

r2s = {n:r2(x=x, y=y**n) for n in exponents}
max(r2s.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
#>>> (1.0, 1.0)
```

As a final note, there is a fancier way to specify getting the 1-positional item from something. You use the built-in library `operator` and the callable `itemgetter`:

```
max(..., key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

The expression `itemgetter(1)` results in an object that is callable -- when it is called on an argument `r` it invokes the `__getitem__` protocol to result in `r[1]`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I think I made a mistake with my question. What I want to do is to guess n so that I will get an R^2 value of 1 (which is the highest value). I tried making sample data in excel and got the following result for a linear trend:

x= (1,2,3,4)
y= (1,2,3,4)
R^2= 1

and
   x= (1,2,3,4)
y= (1,4,9,16)
R^2= 0.969

... which is what your code is giving. It gives the R^2 value for n=1. For instance for the 2nd set of data, it will have a R^2= 1  value if n=2. Sorry for the wrong idea for my question.