How can I calculate the blending factor from a linear combination of two pictures?
I have a sequence of images that are very similar and can be approximately represented as a combination of two 'ground truth' images with added noise, in the form:
Image_i ≈ x_i × Image(1) + (1−x_i) × Image(2) + Noise

where x_i is the mixing coefficient.
I'm looking for the best method in Python to determine the value of xx for each image in the sequence. The images are noisy and I expect x_i to range between 40% and 70%.
The images are relatively small, but I have thousands of them, so the solution should be computationally efficient.
What would be the best approach to solve this problem?
Edit: I added an image 3 which could be a potential image_i


@ChristophRackwitz the author didn't show the final image, only the input images as I may guess.

there are many ways how you can do this.
Usually in case of normal errors you use a loss function that minimize root mean squared error (similar to how Linear regression is estimated).
Solution 1
After creating a loss function you can consider using fsolve to get an optimal x parameter.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

np.random.seed(88)

# --> Generating random input data

width, height = 640, 480
image_1 = np.random.normal(loc = 4, scale = 3, size = [ 640, 470])
image_2 = np.random.normal(loc = 8, scale = 3, size = [640, 470])
noise = np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = [640, 470])

# <-- End of random data generation


# sample unknown parameter
x_i = np.random.rand()
print(f"x_i: {x_i}") 
# x_i: 0.9129151984340369

# create a target image
image_new = x_i * image_1 + (1 - x_i) * image_2 + noise


def rmse_loss(x):
    """ 
        Root mean squared error loss
        loss = sqrt(sum_i[(y_pred[i] - y_true[i])**2])
    """

    estimation =  (x * image_1 + (1 - x) * image_2)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(image_new  - estimation, 2)))

# for attribute `x0` you can use any value, it will converge to the solution eventually
res = fsolve(rmse_loss, x0 = 0)
print(res)
# [0.91293059]

Solution 2
Another option is to note that your equation is equivalent to the following:
image_new - image_2 = x_i * (image_1 - image_2) + noise

And this is exactly the definition of linear regression (b = Ax + noise), which can be solved using linalg.lstsq method:
from scipy import linalg

b = (image_new - image_2).reshape([-1,1])
a = (image_1 - image_2).reshape([-1,1])

res = linalg.lstsq(a,b)

print(res[0][0][0]) 
# 0.91302692

# how good is the fit: R2 value
r2 = 1 - res[1] / np.power(b,2).sum()

print(r2) # 0.965


Several caveats:

I'm considering the situation where Noise have a zero mean;
Methods like fsolve could be hard to scale if you have millions of pictures;


Thanks - I like the solution, in particular #2. How stable are these solutions? Let's assume that one pattern is more blurred (like Gaussian blur) than the two original images, or does not match perfectly - would you still expect this to work? If I read it correctly, it is based on fitting (least squares), so it should work?

Shortly saying RMSE error is your choice. RMSE guarantees to give best solution for linear models with normal noise in errors (and this is your case). However if data was modified by gaussian blur it is not the same as simply adding normal distribution to each pixel. In this case you need to be more specific with how patter was created from original images.

About RMSE robustness: RMSE is optimal for normal (Gaussian) errors, and MAE is optimal for Laplacian errors. When errors deviate from these distributions, other metrics are superior. - for example citing this article: https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/15/5481/2022/

Wonderful - I just created some artificial data and tested - I also tested Gaussian blurring and it yields satisfying results. Thanks a lot!

When I look at the second value, res[1], I get numbers going from 0 to very large numbers. How can I get something meaningful from that? Do I have to normalize it?

Is your question about lstsq? In my answer both solutions return single value x and the second weight should be calculated using formula 1-res[0].

Yes, in principle in your example we look at res[0], but the function returns res[1], res[2] and res[3]. And res[1] should be the residual. I just want to have a way to quantify how well the least square approach worked, kind of an error estimation.

Use R2. In your case the formula to use: r2 = 1 - res[1] / np.power(b,2).sum(). Note that it is a bit different from standard formula, because we don't fit a constant in the linalg.lstsq.

As for R2. The closer to 1, the better. Usually everything above 0.8 is great.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054191/converting-numpy-lstsq-residual-value-to-r2 But in this topic author added vector of ones to his A matrix thus his calculation a bit different.

I think pictures in the question were misleading, but the formula says for itself.

While I trust the res[0][0][0] value (I did several sanity checks, and none of them failed), I don't get good results for R2. Here, I get negative values, such as -100. So it does not work for me. Maybe it is just a normalization problem though.

this is weird. Create a new question with 1-2 images examples and the code that you are using to calcuate R2.
